# Eclipse RCP - JFace dialog doesn't show buttons

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I'm trying to create a custom dialog with a TableViewer inside it. It looks good as Test/Preview but when I actually run my app the buttons at the bottom disappear.

Test/preview when running from inside WindowBuilder looks like this (at the bottom):

[image]

When running in the app it looks like this:

[image]

Here is the source code of the dialog:

```
@Override
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
    Composite container = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
    container.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    Composite composite = new Composite(container, SWT.NONE);
    composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
    TableColumnLayout tcl_composite = new TableColumnLayout();
    composite.setLayout(tcl_composite);

    TableViewer tableViewer = new TableViewer(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    table = tableViewer.getTable();
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);

    TableViewerColumn tableViewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
    TableColumn tblclmnNewColumn = tableViewerColumn.getColumn();
    tcl_composite.setColumnData(tblclmnNewColumn, new ColumnPixelData(150, true, true));
    tblclmnNewColumn.setText("New Column");
    table.getShell().setSize(710, 400);
    return container;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call `setSize` on the Shell you are overriding the size calculated by the layout and causing the buttons to be outside of the dialog.

To control the size of the table set height and width hints on the table grid data:

```
GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
data.widthHint = 710;
data.heightHint = 400;
table.setLayoutData(data);
```